# git - how to revert a wrong rebase after a merge

Tags: git

I have the following simple branch model:

```
A--B--C  <- master       

D--E--F  <- production, origin/production
```

At a point, I merged back to `master`:

```
A--B--C--M  <- master
         /
D--E--F-/   <- production
```

And then tried a rebase of another branch against `master` (using `--onto`) but stood in the wrong place, so the history turned into:

```
A--B--C--M  <- master,production    
         /
D--E--F-/   <- origin/production
```

So, right now, I have `master` and `production` pointing to the same commit, which should be only the one for `master`.

How do I point `production` back to `origin/production`?

Comment: `git checkout production && git reset --hard origin/production`?

Comment: @Whymarrh I thought about that, but wasn't sure how I need to deal with the branches that had the original `production` as parent. Should it be just a simple rebase?

Comment: No rebase. Just as simple as you posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this is a lot clearer if you make sure your labels are on the *right* side, pointing to the branch tip commits, since this is how branch names actually work in Git (they point to one commit, which we call the *tip* of the branch):

```
A--B--C--M   <-- master
        /
 D--E--F     <-- production, origin/production
```

When you did the thing you did, you copied no commits (fortunately) and simply moved the label `production` to point to commit `M`:

```
A--B--C--M   <-- master, production
        /
 D--E--F     <-- origin/production
```

So all you need to do now is put the label back, so that the name `production` means "commit `F`".  To do that, you can use the commands [Whymarrh gave in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236958/git-how-to-revert-a-wrong-rebase-after-a-merge#comment71633443_42236958):

```
git checkout production && git reset --hard origin/production
```

The `git reset --hard` tells Git to:

- reset the *current* branch (`--soft`, `--mixed`, and `--hard` all do this) to point to the target commit `F`;
- reset the index (`--mixed` and `--hard` both do this) to have as its contents, the contents of the target commit `F`; and
- reset the work-tree (only `--hard` does this) to have as its contents, the contents of the target commit `F`.

Because the first step resets the *current* branch pointer, we need the `git checkout` to select `production` as the current branch (unless it's already current, of course).

Resetting the index and work-tree are desired side effects at this point, since we don't plan to carry any of the index or work-tree contents extracted from commit `M` back into a new commit after `F`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, clear explanation and advice :)